# Problems with htmlparser

Tags: java, android, parsing, html-parsing

I need to extract one tag from a page (which contains multiple children) and afterwards split the retrieved text at tags  which contain multiple stars (*). I need to remove the tags with the stars and then split the text in to parts which I would like to store in a StringArray.

I used http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/ before and it worked fine for extracting text out of specific tags.

```
public class ToeGuideParser extends NodeVisitor{

private static final String TAG = "ToeGuideParser";
final String url = "http://p7510.teamovercome.net/?page_id=18";
private String Guide;
Context context;
int tag_number = 0;

public ToeGuideParser () throws ParserException{
    this(null);
}

public ToeGuideParser(Context context) throws ParserException{
    context = this.context;

    long bfr = startStopWatch();

    Parser parser = new Parser (url);
    parser.visitAllNodesWith(this);

    stopStopWatch(bfr);
}

public void visitTag (Tag tag){
    String tagName = tag.getTagName();
    String content = tag.toPlainTextString(); 
    //Log.d(TAG, tagName);
    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("div")){
        Attribute attr = tag.getAttributeEx("class");
        if (attr!=null){
            String value = attr.getValue();
            if (value.equals("entry-content")){
                //save
                Guide = tag.toHtml(true);
                int guide_start = tag.getStartingLineNumber();
                int guide_end = tag.getEndingLineNumber();
                Log.d(TAG, "Guide starts at "+guide_start+" and ends at "+guide_end);
                //Log.d(TAG, Guide);
            }
        }
    }
    if (content.contains("*****")){
        tag_number++;
        int start = tag.getStartingLineNumber();
        int end = tag.getEndingLineNumber();
        Log.d(TAG, tag_number+" = Tag found at "+start+", ends at "+end);
    }
}

private void split (String bfrSplit){
    if (bfrSplit != null){
        //Log.d(TAG, bfrSplit);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*).*>[*]+</\1>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bfrSplit);
                while (matcher.find()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Start index: " + matcher.start());
                    Log.d(TAG," End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
                    Log.d(TAG,matcher.group());
                }
    }
}



public void finishedParsing(){
    //split(Guide);
    Log.w(TAG, "#########");
    Log.w(TAG, "finished");
}

public long startStopWatch(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public String stopStopWatch(long bfr){
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis()-bfr;
    String formatedTime = "Time Taken: "+time+" milli's" ;
    Log.i(TAG, formatedTime);
    return formatedTime;
}

}

public long startStopWatch(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public String stopStopWatch(long bfr){
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis()-bfr;
    String formatedTime = "Time Taken: "+time+" milli's" ;
    Log.i(TAG, formatedTime);
    return formatedTime;
}

}
```

Problems with this code:

- The line numbers returned are completely wrong. (there are even line numbers that are before the Main Topic that match )
- The regex never matches, though I tried it in a regextester with the sourcecode of the page. I only tried the regex because the code with htmlparser doesn't work.

Stacktrace to illustrate:

```
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 1 = Tag found at 11, ends at 11
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 2 = Tag found at 201, ends at 201
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 3 = Tag found at 202, ends at 202
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 4 = Tag found at 237, ends at 237
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 5 = Tag found at 238, ends at 238
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 6 = Tag found at 239, ends at 239
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): Guide starts at 248 and ends at 248
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 7 = Tag found at 248, ends at 248
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 8 = Tag found at 261, ends at 261
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 9 = Tag found at 261, ends at 261
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 10 = Tag found at 280, ends at 280
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 11 = Tag found at 280, ends at 280
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 12 = Tag found at 307, ends at 307
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 13 = Tag found at 318, ends at 318
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 14 = Tag found at 322, ends at 322
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 15 = Tag found at 328, ends at 328
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 16 = Tag found at 350, ends at 350
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 17 = Tag found at 367, ends at 367
D / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): 18 = Tag found at 376, ends at 376
W / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): #########
W / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): finished
I / ToeGuideParser ( 2146): Time Taken: 1021 milli's
```

Comment: Have you considered using jsoup? http://jsoup.org/

Comment: i use it for a couple of projects. It is clearly the best parser i have yet to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the line numbers problem:**
I'm assuming you're wondering why you're getting so many lines that say *"Tag found at"* — there are more than you expected. The problem is that that this line is effectively loading most of the HTML page into one string:

```
    String content = tag.toPlainTextString();
```

The `toPlainTextString()` method includes the text content of the tag's children, so all the parent tags of the tag containing ***** are going to contain ***** too. I think you probably want to use `getText()` instead, which doesn't include the text of the children (see [JavaDoc](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#toPlainTextString%28%29)).

Note that using `toPlainTextString()` like this is best avoided because it would be pretty slow. Because it's called for each tag in the document, you might be forcing the document to be read a hundred times over, unnecessarily...

**For the regex problem:**
You're not actually calling the `split()` method which contains the regex at the moment. But if you were, I assume it would fail because it's trying to match both the start tag, text node and end tag. But HTML Parser only gives you one node at a time, ie:

- `visitTag()` gives you just the start tag
- `visitStringNode()` gives you just the text node
- `visitEndTag()` gives you just the end tag

So your regex would fail because it expects to get the start, text and end all at once. Also, I think you need to escape the asterisk matcher like this: `[\*]+`

If you need to match something across all three node, then you need to add some private variables to your class to record state. ie if `visitTag()` matches the tag you want, then set a boolean saying that the current tag is valid... then when `visitStringNode()` is called it can check that boolean to decide whether to process the text or ignore it. Then unset the boolean when you encounter the end tag.

Comment: I have started using JSoup and it works out well for me. But thanks for clearing up my confusion with htmlparser.